# Create a Lua table from a CPP string

Tags: c++, lua

I'm coding and artificial intelligence using Lua script. And I'd like to push my map in the Lua's stack which is stock in a std::string *. I show you :

My Lua script (just a sketch to display the map) :

```
function        runIa(x, y, map)
   table.foreach(map, print)
   return 0
end
```

Which only displays "0" on stdout

Here is where I fill my std::string * :

```
int                     AI::update()
{
  std::string           *map = new std::string[2];
  pos_x = 0;
  pos_y = 10;

  map[0] = "0101100";
  map[1] = "1101001";
  toot->getGlobal("runIa");
  toot->pushPosToScript(pos_x, pos_y);
  toot->pushMapToScript(map);
  try {
     toot->pcall(3, 1, 0);
  }
  catch (const LuaException & e){
     std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
  }
  return 0;
}
```

And that's how I push it into the Lua's stack :

```
void                    Lua::pushMapToScript(std::string *map)
{
   lua_newtable(_L);

   for (unsigned int i = 0; i < 2; ++i)
   {
      lua_pushnumber(_L, i + 1);
      lua_pushstring(_L, map[i].c_str());
      lua_settable(_L, -3);
    }
 }
```

It works well for the position but not for the map. I can't display what is store in the var `map` in the Lua script. Does someone have any idea ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: What is the problem with the map?

Comment: I don't konw if I push it correctly in the script, Cause my `table.foreach(map, print)` does not display anything.

Comment: `table.foreach` Why do you want to use such a terrible function when you have `pairs` and such available to you?

Comment: Do you want to create a map equivalent in Lua (where your first map element is a key) or an array? And `table.foreach` is deprecated and due to be removed in future versions.

Comment: `table.foreach` was the issue ! I didn't know that it was a terrible funtion but I'll remember it ! Thanks.

Comment: You have a leak in `AI::update()` btw. Why not just use `std::string           map[] = {"0101100", "1101001"};` instead?

Comment: It was just for the example but I need a dynamic size of `map`, so when I delcare the variable I don't know the size of `map`. But I would probably use a `std::vector<string>` instead.